# c# struct weird behavior

Tags: c#, .net-core, struct, idisposable

Found some weird behevior with c# struct and using statement. Not sure why this is happening.
Sample struct:

```
public struct Thing : IDisposable {
    private bool _dispose;

    public void Dispose() {
        _dispose = true;
    }
    public bool GetDispose() {
        return _dispose;
    }
    public void SetDispose(bool dispose) {
        _dispose = dispose;
    }
}
```

And usage of this struct:

```
        var thing = new Thing();
        using (thing) {
            Console.WriteLine(thing.GetDispose());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(thing.GetDispose());
```

I expect here to see the following output:

```
False
True
```

Because Dispose() method is called at the end of using scope.
But I get:

```
False
False
```

If I change struct to class, or use struct and add thing.SetDispose(true); inside using scope, I get expected output

```
False
True
```

My question is why do I get False False with a struct?
I checked with debugger, Dispose() is called every time at the end of using scope.

Comment: would be interesting to see the generated IL

Comment: @pm100 [Here you go](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUAlIcaSwG4CGATpsABZgA7AOaYAvJgEBTAO6YAKv2EMA3MxYkYABky0+goYyIp1J7AgCcuxUIB0AcUnAAImADOABwD2ryQ3qrjUwBfNXUYCyt9e0cXD29fen9QkJQU1AxMV2BOAFcAY2B5a0wQTABJWK9XdgAjCEkmQJJ3TjAOYAaaz08ITAB9ABM3KskA0IzKTEr4hkbTfqG4nzEeXNHk8awunswHZ2GZw1CWGAB2BYOfAJYUk/IqAGUYy99t3sWRo6b1QZeVj/i11IKSCQA==)

Comment: v odd, subtle code change when struct -> class . paging mr skeet

Comment: Why not using a property for "_dispose"?

Answer (score 4):

The structs are value types, so in this piece of code, the original struct will be copied to a new one inside using statement.

Your code at the end will be translated to:

```
var thing = new Thing();                     //thing._dispose == false
using (Thing thing2 = thing) {               //thing2.dispose == false   
     Console.WriteLine(thing2.GetDispose()); //thing2.dispose == false
}                                            //thing2.dispose == true
                                             //BUT thing1.dispose == false
Console.WriteLine(thing.GetDispose());
```

You can read more here: https://ericlippert.com/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box/